# Problem with sql select query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm having a little problem with [PortfelID] column. I need it's ID to be able to use it in function which will return me name about Type of Strategy per client. However by doing this i need to put [PortfelID] in `GroupBy` which complicates the results a lot.

I'm looking for a way to find Type of Strategy and Sum of Money this strategy has. However if i use `Group By [PortfelID]` I'm getting multiple entries per each strategy. Actually over 700 rows (because there are 700 [PortfelID] values). And all I want is just 1 strategy and Sum of [WycenaWartosc] for this strategy. So in total i would get 15 rows or so

Is there a way to use that function without having to add [PortfelID] in Group By?

```
DECLARE @data DateTime
SET @data = '20100930'

SELECT [dbo].[ufn_TypStrategiiDlaPortfelaDlaDaty] ([PortfelID], @data)
      ,SUM([WycenaWartosc]) AS 'Wycena'   
  FROM[dbo].[Wycena]
  LEFT JOIN [KlienciPortfeleKonta]
  ON [Wycena].[KlienciPortfeleKontaID] = [KlienciPortfeleKonta].[KlienciPortfeleKontaID] 
  WHERE [WycenaData] = @data 
  GROUP BY [PortfelID]
```

Where [dbo].[ufn_TypStrategiiDlaPortfelaDlaDaty] is defined like this:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_TypStrategiiDlaPortfelaDlaDaty]
    (
      @portfelID INT,
      @data DATETIME 
    )
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS BEGIN
    RETURN ( SELECT TOP 1
                    [TypyStrategiiNazwa]
             FROM   [dbo].[KlienciPortfeleUmowy]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[TypyStrategii]
                    ON dbo.KlienciPortfeleUmowy.TypyStrategiiID = dbo.TypyStrategii.TypyStrategiiID
             WHERE  [PortfelID] = @portfelID
                    AND ( [KlienciUmowyDataPoczatkowa] <= @data
                          AND ([KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa] >= @data
                          OR KlienciUmowyDataKoncowa IS NULL)
                        )
             ORDER BY [KlienciUmowyID] ASC
           )

   end
```

EDIT:

As per suggestion (Roopesh Majeti) I've made something like this:

```
  SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [dbo].[ufn_TypStrategiiDlaPortfelaDlaDaty] ([PortfelID], @data) = 'portfel energetyka' THEN [WycenaWartosc] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Strategy 1'
 ,SUM(CASE WHEN [dbo].[ufn_TypStrategiiDlaPortfelaDlaDaty] ([PortfelID], @data) = 'banków niepublicznych' THEN [WycenaWartosc] ELSE 0 END) AS 'Strategy 2'
  FROM [dbo].[Wycena]
  LEFT JOIN [KlienciPortfeleKonta]
  ON [Wycena].[KlienciPortfeleKontaID] = [KlienciPortfeleKonta].[KlienciPortfeleKontaID] 
  WHERE [WycenaData] = @data
```

But this seems like a bit overkill and a bit too much of hand job is required. AlexS solution seems to do exactly what I need :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea of how you can do this.

```
DECLARE @data DateTime
SET @data = '20100930'

SELECT 
   TypID,
   SUM([WycenaWartosc]) AS 'Wycena'
FROM 
(
  SELECT [dbo].[ufn_TypStrategiiDlaPortfelaDlaDaty] ([PortfelID], @data) as TypID
  ,[WycenaWartosc]
  FROM[dbo].[Wycena]
  LEFT JOIN [KlienciPortfeleKonta]
  ON [Wycena].[KlienciPortfeleKontaID] = [KlienciPortfeleKonta].[KlienciPortfeleKontaID] 
  WHERE [WycenaData] = @data
) as Q
GROUP BY [TypID]
```

So basically there's no need to group by PortfelID (as soon as you need to group by output of [dbo].[ufn_TypStrategiiDlaPortfelaDlaDaty]).

This query is not optimal, though. Join can be pushed to the outer query in case PortfelID and WycenaData are not in [KlienciPortfeleKonta] table.

UPDATE: fixed select list and aggregation function application

Comment: If i leave `[PortfelID]` without GROUP BY -> `Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Column 'KlienciPortfeleKonta.PortfelID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. `

Comment: IF i add inside `GROUP BY [PortfelID]) as Q` I get `Column 'Q.Wycena' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Sorry for that - looks like I've forgot to fix select list/aggregation. Updated my answer. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the "Case" statement in sql ?
Check the below link for example :
http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-case.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I know about CASE STATEMENT just don't see how i would use it here? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Check this weblink for more suitable syntax example :                        http://weblogs.asp.net/wilczynski/archive/2008/06/03/sum-case-in-sql.aspx

Comment: Just to add.. You can use your profile_ID under each "case" and summation into another field. Hope this helps. If not, let me know.. can try to help you more.

Comment: I see where you are going. But is there a way to create CASE statement dynamically? The list of strategies is about 15 entries now but it can be 16 in a month or even more later on, and users are given option to add it as they please.

Comment: I think then its going to be tricky. But if you are going to have the above required format, then you might need to go with static case statements, than dynamic. However, I feel that, the change is only addition of 1 more case statement, whenever you have one more category. Is the number of case statements going to increase always or rarely ?

Comment: I guess I could do it by hand if there's no other way. It will be increasing with time and i would like to not touch it if possible (i would have to remember to fix it and since my customer may add it without me knowing it's a bit problematic. Isn't there a way to create an `ArrayList` of some sort in SQL and then go thru each entry of that array (table column) and use the values returned to put as CASE condition ? If it's gonna be real pain I can always make it work in C#.

Comment: I've now created simple select with your idea and it seems the way you want it i will have new column per strategy. So if i have 50 strategies i will have 50 columns ?

Comment: I've now updated first post. See if that's how you wanted me to do things?

Comment: It is true to major extent. But there is no need of ELSE statement for each case.. You can just ignore them and try your result once. And YES, if you are going to have 50 Strategies, you will have 50 columns. But i think, that is as per your requirement... right ?

Comment: My requirement was to have 2 columns -> One Strategy and one Price. Alex solution just gave me exactly that without need of doing any code changing later on :-)

Comment: Cool... So you got your problem resolved.. by following AlexS solution .. Good to hear that.